# jquery.autocomplete reverts to invalid previous suggestion on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using [jQuery Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) and users are seeing the following behaviour:

1. User starts typing a string and suggestions are presented
2. User keeps typing until no suggestions are valid any longer (and drop down goes away)
3. User hits tab
4. Autocomplete fills the field with an invalid previous suggestion, wiping away what the user had typed

Any ideas?

This is the Javascript code (from Django template):

```
$("#id_name").autocomplete("{% url name_autocomplete %}", {
     formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {
         values = value.split(",,");
         return values[0];
     },
     formatResult: function(data, value) {
         return value.split(",,")[1];
     },
     highlight: false
});
```

Comment: Yes... plenty of ideas, but an actual answer is pretty hard without see your code.

Comment: I've added the javascript code used

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that the described behavior is *exactly* what the users are doing?  I only ask because it appears that if you type in a autocompletable term, *scroll down to an option*, type enough to create to create an invalid term, and press tab very quickly then the previously *highlighted* suggestion is "submitted".  There appears to be a race condition when a "step 1.5" is added to your behavior: "User presses the down arrow to highlight a suggestion."

If the behavior is indeed precisely as you have described, you may consider using the autocomplete in jQuery UI.  It appears that the version of autocomplete you have linked to is deprecated.  I did a quick test on several different implementations of jQuery UI autocomplete and they do not appear to exhibit the behavior you describe.

Alternatively, there appears to be an update to the version you linked at https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin.  Bug reports and fixes do not appear to be terribly well documented, but perhaps they fixed your issue in the update (either directly or indirectly.)